# weighted average in MySql

Tags: mysql, select, average

I am currently using the following query to get the highest average result:

```
select ContentType, AVG(Result) as AvgContent from dopractice where S_Id =@S_Id group by ContentType order by 2 desc limit 1;
```

I am trying to modify my query to calculate the highest weighted average.

**For example:**

```
((X*1)+(Y*2)+(Z*3))/3
```

Is there a way to do this using a single query?

*Note: the columns in  dopractice table are `(Id, StudentId, LessonId, ContentType, result, Date)`*

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. May be this will helpful for you.

```
    select temp.content,MAX(temp.AvgContent)
    FROM
    (
    select ContentType AS content, AVG(Result) as AvgContent 
    from dopractice 
    where StudentId = @S_Id 
    group by ContentType order by ContentType desc
    ) AS temp
   group by  temp.ContentType;
```

Comment: How do you calculate weighted average in your suggestion?